# Is there a date function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have day and month. I want to know that given date with day/month is expired or not in given year.

````
Eg. day: 2, month: feb (2nd feb)
case 1.
  if today is 10th march, 2020.
  result will be **expired**.
case 2.
  if today is 1st feb, 2020
  result will be **not expired**.```
````

Comment: `Date.new(2020, 3, 10) < Date.new(2020, 2, 2)` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Date`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) implements [`<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) to compare two dates chronologically. It also includes [`Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Comparable.html) so you can use `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, and `>`, e.g.:

```
require 'date'

Date.new(2020, 3, 10) < Date.new(2020, 2, 2) #=> false

Date.new(2020, 2, 1) < Date.new(2020, 2, 2) #=> true
```